# What's the best way to filter resources in RESTful API by user permission?

Tags: rest, api, oauth, scope, authorization

Suppose we have two kinds of users, admins and standard users.

We have a resource called `post`. For GET method, I want admins to see all posts, but standard user to only see posts where `post.created_by={currentUserID}`.

Now I have three options:

- Use `/api/post` and `/api/mypost`. Upside is I can easily control the returned results and assign different permissions based on user scope. Downside is I will repeat the code and documentation.
- Use `/api/post` for both, and for standard users, if it does not have `?createdBy={id}` then refuse the request.
- Use `/api/post` for both, but the method will behave differently depending on the authentication. For standard users the returned list is always filtered. for `/api/post/{id}` it'll return HTTP 403 for posts that doesn't belong to user.

Which one should I choose?

Answer (score 0):

First option is not ideal, because (as you said), it's prone to code duplication.

If the second one would've made sense with not just the currentUserID, it could've worked aswell.

However, given you must do authentication either way, I'd go for the third option, as it's probably the most widespread solution. Different users see different things depending on their permissions/portfolio, in a clean manner, no messing around with the url's query string.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure. But the first option is the best, you almost repeat code, but the code is separated as there is two different use cases. You can do a refactor to prevent code duplication. The most important advantage is that you will get a Design of the system in which every api is agnostic of the auth method and procedures, when building the API, the programmer does not need to know if have to apply a filter or not. And the same route can be used: /api/post and redirects to switch into /api/post and /api/mypost if applies